# Line chart iOS doesn't display chart entries

Tags: ios, swift, charts

So I'm creating a fitness app to display a changing variable `calories burnt today` stored as a Double in User defaults. I want to make it such that every hour, the view controller displaying the line graph would check the User default `calories burnt today` and add a line chart entry containing the value stored in `calories burnt today` and display it on the line graph so that the user would be able to monitor his calories burnt throughout the day.

But the problem is that the first time I segue into the viewController, there is a single point present in the line graph showing the number of calories burnt, but when I next segue into the ViewController, the line graph view is blank!

code is below:

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class DaysViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var graphsview: UIView!
    var linechart = LineChartView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        linechart.delegate = self
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        linechart.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.graphsview.frame.size.width, height: self.graphsview.frame.size.height)
        linechart.center = graphsview.center
        view.addSubview(linechart)
        
        var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
        let caloriesburnt = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "calories burnt today")
        var hours3 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hoursofexerciserecorded")
        UserDefaults.standard
        let date = Date()
        let calender = Calendar.current
        let currenthour = calender.component(.minute, from: date)
        let previoushour = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hour")
        let hour2 = previoushour + 1
        if hour2 <= currenthour {
            hours3 += 1
            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(hours3), y: caloriesburnt))
            UserDefaults.standard.set(hours3, forKey: "daysofexerciserecorded")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currenthour, forKey: "hour")
        }
        
        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)
        linechart.data = data
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm noticing a lot of errors inside this code.

**1st**

Why put this line `view.addSubview(linechart)` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called `n` times so you are adding n `linechart` to your view.

**2nd**

Why do you get dimensions from `graphsview` and then you add your `linechart` to your view?

**3rd**

Remove that `UserDefaults.standard` not used in your code

**Edit (full code)**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    linechart.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourWidht, height: yourHeight)
    linechart.center = graphsview.center
    graphsview.addSubview(linechart)
    setChartData()
}

private func setChartData() {
    var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
    let caloriesburnt = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "calories burnt today")
    var hours3 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hoursofexerciserecorded")
    
     let date = Date()
     let calender = Calendar.current
     let currenthour = calender.component(.minute, from: date)
     let previoushour = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hour")
     let hour2 = previoushour + 1
     if hour2 <= currenthour {
         hours3 += 1
         entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(hours3), y: caloriesburnt))
         UserDefaults.standard.set(hours3, forKey: "daysofexerciserecorded")
         UserDefaults.standard.set(currenthour, forKey: "hour")
     }  
     let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
     set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
     let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)
     linechart.data = data
}
```

Comment: ok i see why so how do i make it such that only one line chart is called?

Comment: add it in viewDidLoad()

Comment: but even after changing according to what you said it still doesn't work though

Comment: ok @Alastar's code worked, all I needed to do was to add a for loop outside of the if statement and in it have the command entries.append.Thx Alastar for the help

Comment: that's great! ;D